# Flutter DataTable select Row

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, row, datarow

I have a problem with DataTable in flutter. I want to change the state of the row, when the user click on one of them, but I found just how to do this "manually" with selected: true, inside DataRow.

How can I let the user select just a single row, and deselect the rest, by changing the state?

```
content: Column(
               children: <Widget>[
                 DataTable(
                   columns: [
                     DataColumn(label: Text('Language')),
                     DataColumn(label: Text('Translation')),
                   ],
                   rows: [
                     DataRow(selected: true, cells: [
                       DataCell(
                         Text(
                           "RO",
                           textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                           style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                         ),
                         onTap: () {
                           setState(() {
                             color = Colors.lightBlueAccent;

                           });
                         },
                       ),
                       DataCell(
                         TextField(
                           decoration: InputDecoration(
                               border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'paine'),
                         ),
                       ),
                     ]),
                     DataRow(cells: [
                       DataCell(
                           Text(
                             "EN",
                             textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                             style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                           ), onTap: () {
                         print('EN is clicked');
                       }),
                       DataCell(
                         TextField(
                           decoration: InputDecoration(
                               border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'bread'),
                         ),
                       ),
                     ]),
                     DataRow(cells: [
                       DataCell(
                           Text(
                             "FR",
                             textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                             style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                           ), onTap: () {
                         print('FR is clicked');
                       }),
                       DataCell(
                         TextField(
                           decoration: InputDecoration(
                               border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'pain'),
                         ),
                       ),
                     ]),
                   ],
                 ),
               ],
             ),
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can copy past run full code below 
You can use condition in `selected` like this `0 == selectedIndex` where 0 is `DataRow` index
and change `selectedIndex` in `onSelectChanged` 
code snippet

```
    int selectedIndex = -1;
    ... 
    rows: [
    DataRow(
        selected: 0 == selectedIndex,
        onSelectChanged: (val) {
          setState(() {
            selectedIndex = 0;
          });
        },
        ...
    DataRow(
        selected: 1 == selectedIndex,
        onSelectChanged: (val) {
          setState(() {
            selectedIndex = 1;
          });
        },
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Color color;
  int selectedIndex = -1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            DataTable(
              onSelectAll: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedIndex = -1;
                });
              },
              columns: [
                DataColumn(label: Text('Language')),
                DataColumn(label: Text('Translation')),
              ],
              rows: [
                DataRow(
                    selected: 0 == selectedIndex,
                    onSelectChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedIndex = 0;
                      });
                    },
                    cells: [
                      DataCell(
                        Text(
                          "RO",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            color = Colors.lightBlueAccent;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      DataCell(
                        TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'paine'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
                DataRow(
                    selected: 1 == selectedIndex,
                    onSelectChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedIndex = 1;
                      });
                    },
                    cells: [
                      DataCell(
                          Text(
                            "EN",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ), onTap: () {
                        print('EN is clicked');
                      }),
                      DataCell(
                        TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'bread'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
                DataRow(
                    selected: 2 == selectedIndex,
                    onSelectChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedIndex = 2;
                      });
                    },
                    cells: [
                      DataCell(
                          Text(
                            "FR",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ), onTap: () {
                        print('FR is clicked');
                      }),
                      DataCell(
                        TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'pain'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I needed to call something when I pressed on the `DataRow` I did the following:

```
DataRow(
onSelectChanged(_) {
// do something here
}
cells: [],
),
```

Maybe this will help?

EDIT: this is a simple example of how to select/deselect rows

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Stack1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Stack1State createState() => _Stack1State();
}

class _Stack1State extends State<Stack1> {
  bool row1Selected = false;
  bool row2Selected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: DataTable(
        columns: [
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('My Data'),
          ),
        ],
        rows: [
          DataRow(
            selected: row1Selected,
            onSelectChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                row1Selected = value;
              });
            },
            cells: [
              DataCell(
                Text('Data 1'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          DataRow(
            selected: row2Selected,
            onSelectChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                row2Selected = value;
              });
            },
            cells: [
              DataCell(
                Text('Data 2'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: And how could I change the "selected" mode inside the method? Or to change the color of the DataRow, anything would be useful..

Comment: @AlexandruBuruiana I'm not sure at the moment, I'll try to find a solution right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
      DataTable(
        dataTextStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 12,
        ),
        headingTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
        dataRowHeight: 100,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Constants.backgroundColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          // border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey,
              spreadRadius: 2,
              blurRadius: 2,
              offset: Offset(1, 1),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        dividerThickness: 2,
        showCheckboxColumn: false,
        onSelectAll: (value) {},
        columns: [
          DataColumn(
              label: Text(
            'Unit No.',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Constants.appColor2),
          )),
          DataColumn(
              label: Text(
            'Unit Type',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Constants.appColor2),
          )),
          DataColumn(
              label: Text(
            'Description',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Constants.appColor2),
          )),
        ],
        rows: List.generate(
          data.length,
          (index) => DataRow(
              selected: selectedUnit == index,
              onSelectChanged: (value) {
                print(value);
                setState(() {
                  selectedUnit = index;
                  unitNumber = data[index].unitId;
                });

                PersistentNavBarNavigator.pushNewScreen(context,
                    screen: ShowProductDetails(
                      unitId: data[index].unitId,
                    ));
              },
              cells: [
                DataCell(Text(
                  data[index].unitId,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Constants.matGold,
                  ),
                )),
                DataCell(Text(
                  data[index].unitType,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Constants.peach,
                  ),
                )),
                DataCell(Text(
                  data[index].decription,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Constants.appColor,
                  ),
                )),
              ]),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Also, consider making it as simple as possible: remove all formatting containers and attributes